# mysql create view - filter duplicated rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, sql-view

My users are splited in user tables over 5 databases. Looks like this:

```
db1.user
id  token  app  lang  last_update
XX  1      a    en    11:00
XX  2      a    en    12:00


db2.user
id  token  app  lang  last_update
XX  1      b    en    12:00
XX  2      a    en    16:00

db3.user
…
```

Now i need all users in one view, it should look like this (token and app are together the primary key):

```
view db.user_all
id  token  app  lang  last_update
XX  1      a    en    11:00
XX  1      b    en    12:00
XX  2      a    en    16:00
```

I tried to union everything:

```
create view `db`.`user_all` AS 
SELECT * FROM `db1`.`user` union 
SELECT * FROM `db2`.`user`
```

The result looks like this:

```
view db.user_all
id  token  app  lang  last_update
XX  1      a    en    11:00
XX  2      a    en    12:00
XX  1      b    en    12:00
XX  2      a    en    16:00
```

My sql statement deletes the duplicated rows, but if the last_update is different i got a duplicated user in the result view. How to solve this? I need all data, also the newest last_update.

Comment: How are you identifying our user? through `id` column?

Comment: in the same database the user has the same id, but not in the second database... there it should be the token and app column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW user_intermediate AS
SELECT * FROM db1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM db2
ORDER BY last_update DESC
;

CREATE VIEW user_all AS
SELECT *
FROM user_intermediate
GROUP BY app, token
;
```

Assuming App and Token make the user key, the user_all view should have the distinct users with the latest last_update across both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a DISTINCT along with a MAX, so something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,  token,  app,  lang,  max(last_update) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `db1`.`user` union 
    SELECT * FROM `db2`.`user`
)
GROUP BY id, token, app, lang
```

you may need to use an alias after the last bracket.

---

**update**

Apparently, MYSQL cannot have subqueries in views so you'll have to create this as a stored procedure instead http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: it says: #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: it's almost the same if i create a second temporary view? one for the subquery? if the "lang" is different between the same user, i would also like to get the "lang" from the max(last_update) user. how to reach this?

Comment: You need to decide what rules you want, if a certain language takes precedence over another or you need the latest...